# Declare global variable from inside if statement (C)

Tags: c, embedded

I am trying to declare a variable from inside an if statement because based upon a condition, the variable will be of a different type to be used later.

```
uint8_t gpio_flag(PORT_t * port, uint8_t pin) {
    if(getType(port)) {     // odd
        DIO_PORT_Odd_Interruptable_Type * _port = port;
    }
    else {                  // even
        DIO_PORT_Even_Interruptable_Type * _port = port-1;
    }

    return ((_port->IFG & (1<<pin))==1);
}
```

Where the Odd_int_type and Even_int_type are both structs that have an IFG member. getType just returns 1 if odd and 0 if even.

However, the scope of _port is within the if statement so it doesn't work. Is there a workaround?

Trying to do this for a project I'm working on with the MSP432P401R microcontroller.

Comment: you can't do that (hopefully), use a union type.

Comment: You have missed the idea of *global*.

Comment: The (MSVC) compiler tells you have a *redefinition* of `_port`. But it's crap anyway, since each should have its own scope, and not be able to be referenced later with `return ((_port->IFG & (1<<pin))==1);` which MSVC does allow.

Comment: Put one copy of the `return` in the `if` code and another in the `else` code.  That'll work.  Otherwise, why is there a difference between the even and odd interruptible port types?  Use a common type to represent the common behaviour.

Comment: this whole thing looks odd to me. Are `PORT_t`, `DIO_PORT_Odd_Interruptable_Type`, and `DIO_PORT_Even_Interruptable_Type` all the same types? If not, I would expect some compiler warnings/errors about trying to assign one pointer type to another. If so, why the different names? And what is `port-1` going to give you?

Comment: Show us how the DIO_PORT_*_Interruptable_Type's are declared.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable inside the if scope, it won't be accesible outside it due to the scope limitation. 
Assuming you just want to point to different data depending on odd/even port, you just need to increase the scope of _port to whatever you need.
If you are trying to access same memory with different variables, one way you can do it is using a `union` of structs. You will need to increase the scope of the variable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare anything outside the current scope that isn't extern. You can declare _port variable in function, file or global scope, then set its value in your `gpio_flag` function. If `DIO_PORT_Odd_Interruptable_Type` and `DIO_PORT_Even_Interruptable_Type` are aliases for PORT_t, then you can simply define `PORT_t _port;` and track whether it is odd or even with `bool _portIsEven;`.